# How to remove an End-User Agreement Window

Tags: installation, sharpdevelop, software-lifecycle

I have completed my installation packages of my exe file ,
I am using `SharpDevelop` for it.

My issue is : how could I remove "`End-User Agreement Window`" from appearing to the user.

by using some scripts on SharpDevelop Project or by any other possible way.

Answer (score 0):

SharpDevelop allows you to create installers using WiX, so I am assuming that is what you are creating. If you take a look at the [WiX documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) there is a section on customising the dialog sequence and shows you how to skip one of the dialogs. I have duplicated the information below from the WiX website, this assumes you are using the InstallerDir UI.

1. Copy the  element defined in [WixUI_InstallerDir.wxs](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_InstallDir.wxs) which is available from [GitHub](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3)
2. Remove the  elements that are used to add Back and Next events
   for the LicenseAgreementDlg.
3. Change the  element that is used to add a Next event to the WelcomeDlg to go to the InstallDirDlg instead of the LicenseAgreementDlg.